# From and To Month-year range selector

Tags: dates, combobox

Requirement in our app is to provide a UI control for user to select 'from' month/year and 'to' month/year over multiple year.
With validations like 'to' month cann't be less than 'from' month.

Example:- User should be able to select Feb-2013 to Mar-2014
Or just Jun-2014 to Jun-2014, etc.

The most simple UI I can think of is by using four combo dropdown to select fromMonth, fromYear, toMonth and toYear.

[image: Month and Year range selector]

Some drawbacks of this patter are:-

- User need to click 4 *2 = 8 times to select from and to.
- Time period selection or magnitude is not intuitive, (No visual way to tell 6 months or full year is selected)
- To know the full range of months and years available, user need to click all four combos.

Please let me know of any better UI pattern or controls for above requirements.

Comment: This thread is about just month-year selector.
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48065/best-practice-for-selecting-month-year